# Why isn't f-string the default in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, f-string

I have previously used string formatting using `format()`. I have seen code where `%` is used for formatting. Recently I started using f-strings and they are more flexible and easy to use than the other above mentioned approaches. f-strings also seemed more generic (for example, you don't need to use an extra method like `.format()`). The advantages over the other methods are given here in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale).

Why is f-string NOT the default? If it was default, I would not have add `f` before the string when I use it. I can directly. In other words, what are the pitfalls in using f-string over other string formatting schemes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's up for debate and not a clear question.

Comment: _Maybe_ f-strings by default would be nice, but it would be a backwards-compatibility break so it would not be possible until Python 4.0 - and given how badly the Python-3.0 transition went that kind of break may never happen in Python again.

Answer (score 2):

It can not be the default behavior because it would totally break existing code like this:

```
template = "hello {who}"
data = {"who": "world"}
rendered = template.format(**data)
```

If f-strings were the default you would get:

```
NameError: name 'who' is not defined
```

Comment: You're right. Backward compatibility makes sense.